# Using classes in nestjs with strict enabled

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm working with [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) while strict is enabled in `tsconfig.json`.

This causes some unexpected behavior with validation. Because we are using the `class-validator` library for DTO validation, we have to create DTOs as classes, and because we have strict enabled, and in particular `strictNullChecks:true` enabled, we have to explicitly initialize every property in the class that is not optional.

If we initialize properties with default values, `class-validator` will fail to validate the DTO for non-existent properties because there will be default values in all properties then nestjs will call `new' on the class.

In addition, nest will call default constructor on the DTO and will not pass the received value into the constructor and so I cannot implement constructor that receives initial value.

So as far as I can see now I'll either need to disable `strictNullChecks:true` or find another way to validate DTO's.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) ("!") within your DTO. You should then make shure that you use the right decorators to prevent that this property will be null or undefined. You can explicitly allow `undefined` if that is a valid option for a property.

```
export class MyDto {
    @IsString()
    readonly willNotBeUndefined!: string; // <-- notice the "!"

    @IsOptional()
    readonly couldBeUndefined?: string;

    //   Or like this: 
    //   @IsOptional()
    //   readonly couldBeUndefined: string | undefined;
}
```

Comment: We've tried it and it actually proved to be not that good. Programmers tend to abuse the non null assertion operator. Wrote a short blog post about it https://medium.com/att-israel/my-relationship-with-operator-58b0dc524144

Comment: Yes, it is not ideal but I guess it is the best that we have at the moment for your described use case. At least it is better than setting strictNullChecks to false. That would be like implicitly putting "!" everywhere in your entire code base. This way you can limit the less strict settings to the lines where you put the "!" and you make it explicit. But if you have a better solution please let me know. :)